# How to save element into collection with out defining in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add an element into schema object in a middleware pre save method, I defined the config as strict: false. So expecting this new element to be added and saved to the object. Below is my code which I am working on.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var User = new Schema({
    author    : String
  , type      : String
}, { strict: false });

var MyUserModel = mongoose.model('User', User); //create and access the model User

var u = new MyUserModel({author:'mark',type:'novel'});

u.pre('save', function(next, req){
var self = this;
self.view = 'ALL';
    console.log("pre save");
next();
});
u.save(function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

The problem is unable to save the new element(**view**) into the collection.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`set`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-set):

```
self.set('view', 'ALL');
```

For properties that aren't in the schema, Mongoose cannot create a setter (whereas for properties that *are* in the schema, it does, and so `self.author = '...'` *would* work), so you have to set it explicitly.